# Thymeleaf Spring MVC form - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf form that is throwing the following exception after it's submitted

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
```

I've read a couple of answers which suggests putting a `BindingResult` directly after the model attribute in the controller method but this doesn't seem to have solved it. Here's what I have

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/capturedetails}" th:object="${command}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group" th:if="${mobilePhone} == null">
    <label for="mobilePhone">Mobile Phone</label> <input
      type="tel" class="form-control"
      id="mobilePhone"
      placeholder="Mobile Phone no." th:field="*{mobilePhone}"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" th:if="${secondEmail} == null">
    <label for="secondEmail">Secondary Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control"
      id="secondEmail" placeholder="Secondary Email" th:field="*{secondEmail}"></input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The controller method

```
@PostMapping(value = "/capturedetails")
public String updateProfile(@ModelAttribute("command") CaptureDetailsFormCommand command, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", command);
    return "redirect: someWhere";
}
```

And the command object

```
public class CaptureDetailsFormCommand {

    private String mobilePhone;

    private String secondEmail;

    public String getMobilePhone() {
        return mobilePhone;
    }

    public void setMobilePhone(String mobilePhone) {
        this.mobilePhone = mobilePhone;
    }

    public String getSecondEmail() {
        return secondEmail;
    }

    public void setSecondEmail(String secondEmail) {
        this.secondEmail = secondEmail;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK in my usual style, solved it myself. The problem was actually in the Get Mapping not the post mapping eg. I needed

```
@GetMapping(value = "/capturedetails")
public ModelAndView captureDetails() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("capturedetails");
    mav.addObject("command", new CaptureDetailsFormCommand());
    return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the name of the model attribute to your form like so:

```
<form action="#" modelAttribute="command" ...
```

And check the bindingResult has no errors like so:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/capturedetails")
public String updateProfile(@ModelAttribute("command") CaptureDetailsFormCommand command, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
       return "error"; //This should return some kind of error
    }
    ....
```

Comment: That's the equivalent of `th:object="${command}"` in thymeleaf which I have set